# How can I draw a line to connect blocks in tikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

I am using tikzposter and I would like to connect blocks with lines/arrows to indicate the sequence in which the boxes should be read. I was wondering whether tikzposter defines names for the blocks and if these can be used in a path... (Or any other solution to my problem)

I guess one could draw on the page by trial and error, but I am hoping there is a better way.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[colspace=5cm]{tikzposter}

\title{How do I draw lines connecting blocks 1--2--3--4?}
\author{Stefano Ghirlanda}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5}

\block{Block 1}{ Block 1 text }

\block{Block 4}{ Block 4 text }

\column{0.5}

\block{Block 2}{ Block 2 text }

\block{Block 3}{ Block 3 text }

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! You are more likely to get help if you give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `tikzposter.cls`, the definition of `\block` is in lines 355-444.

The title and body of a block are given separate names, `blocktitle` and `blockbody`. But the same name is always used, they're not unique.

You can however use the `fit` library to make new nodes. For example, if you do

```
\block{foo}{bar}
\node [fit=(blockbody),inner sep=0pt,draw,line width=2mm,yellow,dashed] (a) {};
\node [fit=(blocktitle),inner sep=0pt,draw,line width=2mm,red,loosely dashed] (b) {};
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

So you can see where the outlines of those nodes are.

For convenience you can make a new command for making and naming a node that fits title and body of a block. It has to be used immediately after a block, of course.

[image: output of code below]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\NameBlock[1]{\node[fit=(blockbody)(blocktitle),inner sep=5pt] (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{foo}{bar}
\NameBlock{a}
\column{0.5}
\block{bar}{baz}
\NameBlock{b}
\end{columns}

\draw [-stealth, line width=2mm] (a.south) to[bend right=40] (b.south);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great! I tweaked a bit removing the blockbody and having inner sep=-5pt so that I can draw arrows connecting the rounded title boxes that are used in my theme.